# Any way to continue iter(list) after StopIteration by adding items to list?

Tags: python, iterator

I would like to do something like

```
>>> lst = [1, 2]

>>> i = iter(lst)

>>> next(i)
1

>>> next(i)
2

>>> next(i)
Traceback (most recent call last): StopIteration

>>> lst.append(3)   #
                    # append some more values
>>> lst.append(4)   #

>>> next(i)         # !!!
3                   # this does not work in Python 3.4;
                    #   I get StopIteration again
```

Context: I am writing some factorization code; if I run out of stored primes to test with, I would like to find a bunch more, then continue where I left off.

More concretely, I want to do something like

```
n = 600851475143933         # number to factorize
factors = []
primes = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11]   # currently contains about 850,000 primes;
                            #   I'd like not to restart from the beginning
                            #   each time.

p_iter = iter(primes)
while True:
    try:
        p = next(p_iter)

        # fully factored?
        if p*p > n:
            if n > 1:
                factors.append(n)
            break

        # pull out as many p's as possible
        while not(n % p):
            factors.append(p)
            n //= p

    except StopIteration:
        append_more_primes(primes)
        # and continue where I left off
```

but I think I'm going to have to write an infinite-prime-sequence generator which handles this internally; `yield from primes` then yield new primes as I append them.

Any other suggestions on how to do this cleanly while keeping it fast?

Comment: You need to look at `yield`. It lets you create a generator that can do as much work as necessary between each value returned. The output isn't a set of disjoint lists but a single continuous stream.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the whole list all the time. You just append to the right end and pop from the left one. So use

```
primes.append(elem)
```

and

```
elem = primes.pop(0)
```

Here your code:

```
while True:
    if not primes:
        append_more_primes(primes)

    p = primes.pop(0)
    # ... your code
```

You can use [collections.deque](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#collections.deque) as well.

Comment: I am going to be using the list of primes many times; I have no desire to `pop` anything from it; so a deque offers no advantages over a list. What I want, I guess, is a self-caching endless sequence generator.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it.  I've changed the problem ever so slightly so that you are looking at evens rather than primes since it's just easier for me to do the test to see if something is even.

```
def provide_evens():
    i = 0
    while True:
        if i%2 == 0:
            yield i
        i+=1

for next_even in provide_evens():
    print next_even
    if next_even>10:
        break
```

Output is:

> 0
>
> 2
>
> 4
>
> 6
>
> 8
>
> 10
>
> 12

For your problem, after each yield, you need to somehow get the next prime lined up.

Comment: I appreciate the kind thoughts, but I am already quite familiar with generator functions (see the second-last sentence in the question, and my solution below).

Answer (score 0):

For those who are interested, here's what I ended up with (the most relevant bit is the `.infinite_sequence` method).

```
from bisect import bisect_left
from functools import reduce
from operator import mul

def product_(lst):
    return reduce(mul, lst)

class Primes:
    def __init__(self, n):
        """
        Use a modular sieve based on the first n primes
        """
        self.primes = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29]
        self.upto   = 30
        assert 1 < n < len(self.primes)

        self.basis, self.primes = self.primes[:n], self.primes[n:]
        self.wheel_size = ws = product_(self.basis)
        self.wheel = [i - ws for i in range(ws, ws * 2) if all(i % b for b in self.basis)]
        self.wheel_set = set(self.wheel)

        # complete all primes <= wheel_size
        if self.upto < ws:
            for i in self.wheel:
                if i > self.upto:
                    for p in self.primes:
                        if p*p > i:
                            self.primes.append(i)
                            break
                        elif not(i % p):
                            break
            self.upto = ws

        # from now on, self.upto must always be a multiple of wheel_size
        assert self.upto % ws == 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.infinite_sequence()

    def infinite_sequence(self, include_basis=True):
        """
        Yield an infinite sequence of prime numbers
        """
        primes = self.primes
        ws     = self.wheel_size
        wheel  = self.wheel

        # start with the primes we already have stored
        if include_basis:
            yield from self.basis
        yield from primes

        # infinite loop
        while True:
            # calculate next block of primes
            new_primes = []
            upto = self.upto
            for w in wheel:         # automatically excludes basis primes
                i = upto + w        # next candidate
                for p in primes:    # test factors
                    if p*p > i:
                        # new prime found
                        new_primes.append(i)
                        break
                    elif not(i % p):
                        # found a factor - not prime
                        break
            # copy back to stored primes
            primes.extend(new_primes)
            self.upto += ws
            # and yield new values
            yield from new_primes

    def is_prime(self, n):
        if n <= self.upto:
            # must be in already-found primes
            return self.primes[bisect_left(self.primes, n)] == n
        else:
            # test against basis primes
            if (n % self.wheel_size) not in self.wheel_set:
                return False
            else:
                # test possible prime factors
                for p in self.infinite_sequence(False):
                    if p*p > n:
                        return True
                    elif not(n % p):
                        return False

    def factorize(self, n):
        factors = []
        for p in self:
            if p*p > n:
                if n > 1:
                    factors.append(n)
                return factors
            while not(n % p):
                # pull out all factors of p
                factors.append(p)
                n //= p

primes = Primes(5)
```